Schmitt trigger recheck on Proteus 8
Given Vlow thresold=1.5V, Vhigh thresold=4.5V, Vref=5V, Vout=5V. so i got R1=3kOhm, R2=10kOhm.


Only sine wave, without square wave. What i am missing here?

Missing Vin+ and Gen cannot go to Vin- without R, No positive feedback R's, Too many crossing lines on schematic.  Go research a better solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


What i am missing here?

Plenty of things...
It's not a Schmitt trigger that you have simulated. A Schmitt trigger uses positive feedback to the non-inverting input but sadly, you have nothing connected to the non-inverting input at all.
Additionally you have connected the input source directly to the inverting input and, even if you had used positive feedback, that would be neutralized by where you connected the input source.
It gets worse because the positive supply also connects to the output pin and R1 is shorted out AND your source connects to ground but, that ground node is not referenced in you op-amp circuitry. All your oscilloscope is showing is the input signal. Trace the connections to see what I mean.
